# Cache layer to json api (on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, phoenix-framework, json-api

I have a small social website on rails (planing to port to phoenix) that use react on view and backend is just a JSON API, 
with more o less 3000 users online at any moment. It runs with postgres/memcached

When user, for example, visits its feed page, I do:

1. Select activities from database (20 per page)
2. Select last 4 comments from each activity from database (justo 1 select)
3. Select all users referenced by activity or comment from database (select users.* from users where id in (1,3,4,5,...100) )

I have a cache layer (memcached) that when I will load users, first I try load from memcached, if it not exists I read from database and put it on cache.
BUT I also have some "listenners" on users model (and over others referenced models like address and profile) to invalidate cache if any field change.

The problem:

1. This cache demand a lot of code.
2. Sometimes cache run out of sync.
3. I hate to have this listeners and they are "side effects"

My question is: Any one is doing something like that?? 
I search A LOT over all google about cache layer to json api and looks like that everyone is just using database directly.

I know that Rails has it own soluction  (and I gess that phoenix dont has one), but it always end up using update_at column, that means, I have to go to database anyway.

alternative:

1. Live with date, life is not pretty
2. Buy a more powerful postgres instance... any one is using memcached like that.
3. Remover listeners, put some expires_in (1 or 2 minutos... or more) and let app

show out of sync data for a couple of minutes.

thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you looked into Jbuilder?  It has a simple mechanism to invalidate the cache.

Comment: As I know there is only 2 ways to keep cache valid.
1) Invalidate it on certain event, as you do. 2) Rely on changable cache key like `updated_at`